# Mostrar mensaje cuando todos los div se ocultan

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me gustaría mostrar un mensaje cuando no quedan div visibles

¿Cual sería la manera correcta de realizarlo con jquery o javascript?

```js
$("#ocul1").click(function(){
  $("#div1").toggle();
});

$("#ocul2").click(function(){
  $("#div2").toggle();
});

$("#ocul3").click(function(){
  $("#div3").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>

<div style="display:none;">No hay ningún div para mostrar</div>

<br>
<br>

<button id="ocul1">Ocultar / Mostrar Div1</button>
<br><br>
<button id="ocul2">Ocultar / Mostrar Div2</button>
<br><br>
<button id="ocul3">Ocultar / Mostrar Div3</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar una clase y crear una funcion para chequear la visibilidad.  Algo asi:

```js
function checkVisible() {
  var divs = $(".div:visible");
  if (!divs[0]) {
    $("#msg").show();
  } else {
    $("#msg").hide();
  }
}

$("#ocul1").click(function(){
  $("#div1").toggle();
  checkVisible();
});

$("#ocul2").click(function(){
  $("#div2").toggle();
  checkVisible();
});

$("#ocul3").click(function(){
  $("#div3").toggle();
  checkVisible();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="div">div1</div>
<div id="div2" class="div">div2</div>
<div id="div3" class="div">div3</div>

<div id="msg" style="display:none;">No hay ningún div para mostrar</div>

<br>
<br>

<button id="ocul1">Ocultar / Mostrar Div1</button>
<br><br>
<button id="ocul2">Ocultar / Mostrar Div2</button>
<br><br>
<button id="ocul3">Ocultar / Mostrar Div3</button>
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto!